# How HYPGEOM.DIST(A2,A3,A4,A5,True) function works in Excel if i given the cumulative argument as TRUE?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to know about how ***HYPGEOM.DIST()*** function works in Excel, if given cumulative value as ***True***. Actually which function works based on the Probability mass function formula. This formula works well  if i given the cumulative argument as ***False*** like this ***=HYPGEOM.DIST(1,4,8,20,FALSE)*** and return result as ***0.3633***. But if i given the cumulative argument as ***True*** Excel returns result as **0.4654**. I don't know how it is calculated in Excel for ***True*** argument so anyone can share your opinion.

**Probability mass Function:**
[image: Probability mass Function Formula]

x=1 ,n=4 ,M=8 ,N=20;

Solution:
=((8!/(1!(8-1)!)*((12!)/(3!(12-3)!)) / (20!)/((4!)(20-4)!))

=1760/4845

=0.3633

Answer (score 1):

With Cumulative = True you get the total probability for all values up to and including the given of the first argument. I've checked, the following is thus TRUE:

```
=(HYPGEOM.DIST(1,4,8,20,TRUE) = (HYPGEOM.DIST(0,4,8,20,FALSE)+HYPGEOM.DIST(1,4,8,20,FALSE)))
```

You can read [about the Hypgeom excel function here.](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Hypgeom-Dist-Function.html)